# Nameserver is not authoritative for my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, dns-zone, google-cloud-dns

It's more than 48h ago, since I've updated the nameservers of my domain "blocky.host" to Google Cloud DNS.

However my domain is not propargating as seen [here](https://dnschecker.org/#NS/blocky.host)
If I check my domain on diverse web-tools, I get these errors:

`Nameserver ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com/2001:4860:4802:32::6b did not return NS records. RCODE was REFUSED`

`Nameserver is not authoritative for blocky.host`

This is my GCP console:
[image]

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by deleting that zone and creating a new one. Google Cloud assigned me new nameservers, which are working now!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have set up the glue records with the domain registrar, but it looks like there are no records for your domain at the name servers.

**`blocky.host` glue records:**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.14.2 <<>> +norec @c.nic.host blocky.host. NS
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50758
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;blocky.host.                   IN      NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
blocky.HOST.            3600    IN      NS      ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.
blocky.HOST.            3600    IN      NS      ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.
blocky.HOST.            3600    IN      NS      ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.
blocky.HOST.            3600    IN      NS      ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.

;; Query time: 65 msec
;; SERVER: 2a02:e180:3::2#53(2a02:e180:3::2)
;; WHEN: Mon Aug 26 20:06:19 Central Daylight Time 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 172
```

**`blocky.host` Start of Authority Record:**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.14.2 <<>> +norec @ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com blocky.host. SOA
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 63547
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;blocky.host.                   IN      SOA

;; Query time: 61 msec
;; SERVER: 2001:4860:4802:32::6b#53(2001:4860:4802:32::6b)
;; WHEN: Mon Aug 26 20:11:12 Central Daylight Time 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 40
```

So, essentially, you have a domain name and you have glue records to domain name servers. But you have no domain name records on those domain name servers. You will need to log into your google cloud services control panel and correct the issue there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you please provide steps on how to correct the issue? For me as a "beginner" this tells me nothing. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I do not know how google's cloud services control panel is laid out, so giving step by step instructions for them is not something I can do. Let me ask this, you _have_ signed up for [Google's Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/dns/), correct? If so, I believe it comes with technical support services that can help walk you through the use of their interface.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my question with a screenshot of the CGP console. Because normally I never had any issues with using GCP DNS. But now I somehow do and I really cannot figure out how to solve it. Maybe you can take a quick look at it.